# How to set multiple font-size in font property?

Tags: css

When I want to have some spare fonts, I use font property, it's a classic case.

```
font: 30px Regular, "Segoe UI";
```

But it's necessary to change font size too. Code below doesn't work:

```
font: 30px Regular, 40px "Segoe UI";
```

I use SCSS in my project, could i do this with help of it?

Comment: if everything else is the same, why not override with `font-size:40px`?

Answer (score 1):

"Font" property used as shorthand for other properties which customize font settings , and not for multiple fonts set

Answer (score 1):

its not possible to set font size for two time in a single shorthand property.

Answer (score 0):

the only correct way is to use CSS inheritance system for this.

thanks for asnwers.